# ZipOutputStream generates corrupted zip file when zipenty is numerous

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetzip, sharpziplib

I have the code below to simulate an action i am trying to perform using SharpZipLib. The generated zip file runs well when the limit of 'i' is low. But as 'i' tends towards a high value e.g 100, the generated zip file is corrupted. When I repair it, it opens okay. Is there any mistake i am making. Thanks.

```
using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(memoryStream))
{
    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(3);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("Test" + i.ToString() + ".xlsx");
        zipEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
        using (Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(@templatePath))
        {
            StreamUtils.Copy(inputStream, zipOutputStream, 
              new byte[inputStream.Length]);
            inputStream.Close();

            zipOutputStream.CloseEntry();
        }
    }

    zipOutputStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
    zipOutputStream.Close();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    WorkbookUtil.StreamFileToBrowser("Report.Zip", memoryStream.GetBuffer());
}
```

WorkbookUtil.StreamFileToBrowser is my static method to download files to the user browser

### Update:

This is the Method for downloading to Browser

```
public static void StreamFileToBrowser(string sFileName, byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.ContentType = GetMimeTypeByFileName("application/zip");
            context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);

            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have proof that the corruption occurs in the generation and not in the "stream to browser"? If you save the file locally instead, is it still corrupted?

Comment: I have just updated the question to show how i download the file to browser. But for now i cant tell where it occurs.

Comment: @Remus I have saved the stream to local disk and there is no problem. So I guess the problem is with the download.